# How to edit Magento Admin's Order detail page?

Tags: magento, view, edit, ecommerce-sales

I'm want to edit the shipping address div at: admin/sales_order/view/order_id, this is the Magento Admin's Order detail page, I believe.

I've tried with some files at: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view, but I've got nothing. Does anyone knows how to do this? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to edit specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can active backend hints to be sure that this is the correct template with:
http://www.damianculotta.com.ar/2009/07/11/mostrar-phtmls-y-bloques-usados-en-el-skin-de-backend-de-magento/
next you should create a layout update for the backend for the admin area. You might not write in the templates of the adminhtml, because this be lost in Magento Update.
You can be an example in:

```
mage/adminhtml/etc/config.xml



<layout>
            <updates>
                <adminhtml>
                    <file>main.xml</file>
                </adminhtml>
                <report>
                    <file>report.xml</file>
                </report>
                <catalog>
                    <file>catalog.xml</file>
                </catalog>
                <customer>
                    <file>customer.xml</file>
                </customer>
                <promo>
                    <file>promo.xml</file>
                </promo>
            </updates>
</layout>
```

Comment: ..thanks davidselo, but I've got it by showing the template paths hints on admin screen.